# RHEL: Mount 4TB USB drive

Tags: hard-drive, redhat-enterprise-linux, usb-storage

I have a 4TB USB drive that I want to use as a backup. I'm wondering if my 32 bit RHEL 5 system can handle it or if I need to find a 64 bit version.

Via `dmesg` I see it getting recognized as /dev/sdd1 but there are other messages that make me wonder what's going on:

```
scsi6 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
usb-storage: device found at 13
usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
  Vendor: DMI       Model: ST4000DM000-1F21  Rev: 1.08
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 04
sdd : very big device. try to use READ CAPACITY(16).
SCSI device sdd: 7814037167 512-byte hdwr sectors (4000787 MB)
sdd: Write Protect is off
sdd: Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
sdd: assuming drive cache: write through
sdd : very big device. try to use READ CAPACITY(16).
SCSI device sdd: 7814037167 512-byte hdwr sectors (4000787 MB)
sdd: Write Protect is off
sdd: Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
sdd: assuming drive cache: write through
sdd: sdd1 sdd2
sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sdd
sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
usb-storage: device scan complete
usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 26
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 27
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 28
usb 2-1: device not accepting address 28, error -71
usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 29
usb 2-1: device not accepting address 29, error -71
hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

This will replace an existing 2Tb drive that I had mounted using `NTFS-3G` filesystem. My first thought was to repartition it into 2 2Tb drives but I need the full space as it will be used via `rsync` to maintain backups.

Using `fdisk -l`:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! 
   The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

WARNING: The size of this disk is 4.0 TB (4000787029504 bytes).
DOS partition table format can not be used on drives for volumes
  larger than 2.2 TB (2199023255040 bytes). Use parted(1) and GUID
  partition table format (GPT).

Disk /dev/sdd: 4000.7 GB, 4000787029504 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 484501 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16128 * 512 = 8257536 bytes

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1      266306  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT
```

On one hand it sees the 4TB of space but only recognizes 2TB of it.

Suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `gparted` to find the relevant partition (turned out to be /dev/sdd2).

Made a folder under /mnt and connected the drive as `mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdd2 /mnt/sdd2`.